# Why do I get a page not found 404 error when I ran my code with a app? It worked fine without an app

Tags: python, django

When I made my django project using Django(version 1.9.1) and Python (version 3.6.3), a 404 error came. Code follows.

**Error Message :**

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:

1. ^admin/
   The current URL, music, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

**Main URL file :**

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
    ]
```

**App urls file:**

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

**"Views" file for the app :**

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse


    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("<h1> This is the Music Section of the page                                 
    </h1>")
```

Comment: Did you add your app to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py?

Comment: If `^music/` is missing from your error message, then either your main URL file is in the wrong place, or you need to double check that you've saved your files and restarted `runserver` so that you're running the latest version of your code.

Comment: Note that Django 1.9.X is end of life and insecure. If you're learning Django you should start with 2.2.X or 3.0.X. If you're following a tutorial or book, it would be better to find one written for a newer version of Django, which uses new features like `path()` instead of `url()`.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: I am following TheNewBoston(Bucky Roberts for his tutorials on Django)